# Not able to cover a function with org.openide.nodes.Node method call using EasyMock

Tags: java, maven, junit4, easymock, openide

I recently came across a weird problem with EasyMock.
Here's the class which I am testing

```
package com.test.junits;

import org.openide.nodes.Node;

public class IsRoot {
    public boolean isRoot(Node node) {
        Node parentNode = node.getParentNode();
        return (parentNode == null);
    }
}
```

And here is the Junit class

```
package com.test.junits

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openide.nodes.Node;

public class IsRootTest {

private IsRoot isroot;
private Node node;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    isroot = new IsRoot();
    node = EasyMock.createMock(Node.class);
}

@Test
public void gettingExpectationsForGetParentFromNode() {
    Node node = EasyMock.createMock(Node.class);
    Node parentNode = EasyMock.createMock(Node.class);

    EasyMock.expect(node.getParentNode()).andReturn(parentNode);

    EasyMock.replay(node);
    isroot.isRoot(node);
    EasyMock.verify(node);
}
```

When I try running it I get the following exception (with maven and eclipse)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:521)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:499)
    at com.test.junits.IsRootTest.gettingExpectationsForGetParentFromNode(IsRootTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Am I missing something here?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494969/easymock-3-0-mocking-class-throws-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-last-call

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<s>It's probably something to do with the fact you have a local field called `node` and a class variable called `node` both of which are `Node` classes and both of which are mocks.</s>

I would remove the test local `node` altogether, or rename it if you really want a test-local mock `node`

*EDIT*

My previous answer was wrong, and should really have been a comment.
The hidden objects weren't causing any problems. (Although I still think they should have been removed/renamed)

The actual problem here is that the method you are trying to mock is `final` and as such, can't be mocked.

When EasyMock mocks method/classes, it does so by extending and overriding them. So final classes and final methods cannot be mocked with EasyMock as they can't be overridden.

The call to the `getParentNode()` method is not mocked and as such isn't registered during the record state within the expectation call.

Comment: I tried same code. Its not an issue with name or variable. Easymock not able to verify it.

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy You're not wrong. I've found that the method  being mocked is final and altered my answer. Having said that, field hiding is never a good plan, even in tests.