# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available

Tags: spring, unitils

Hi im doing some unit testing using unitils and I always get this Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:175)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:157)
    at package.service.test.BlogspotServiceTest.testGetBlogSpotList(BlogspotServiceTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:156)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

**My Project;**

-**BlogspotTest**

--***src***

---hibernate.cfg.xml

--***test***

---package.service.test

----BaseServiceTest

----BlogspotServiceTest

--***web***

---WEB-INF

----blogspot-servlet-test.xml

----jdbc-test.xml

Here is my BaseServiceTest

```
@SpringApplicationContext({"file:web/WEB-INF/blogspot-servlet-test.xml"})
public class BaseServiceTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {
}
```

Here is my BlogspotServiceTest

```
public class BlogspotServiceTest extends BaseServiceTest{

    @Mock
    @InjectInto(property = "blogspotDAO")
    @SpringBean("blogspotDAO")
    private BlogspotDAO blogspotDAOMock;

    @TestedObject
    @SpringBean("blogspotService")
    private BlogspotService blogspotServiceMock;

    @Test
    public void testUpdateBlogSpot() {
    // to make it simple I try this but still i got the exception i mention above.
        expect(1).andReturn(1); 


    }
}
```

am i missing something ? please lead me to the right path.  tnx

Inside my blogspot-service-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="file:web/WEB-INF/jdbc-test.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
     </bean>

     <!-- DAO'S -->
     <bean id="blogspotDAO" class="package.dao.impl.BlogspotDAOImpl"/>

     <!-- SERVICES -->
     <bean id="blogspotService" class="package.service.impl.BlogspotServiceImpl"/>


     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
     </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

I dont think my jdbc-test.properties is necessary but for the sake of completing the requirements here it is,

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbspringminiblogtest
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

**Update :**

During my research I found [this](https://stefanhendriks.wordpress.com/tag/easymock/),

> *One little piece of advice when writing your test, is that the*
>   *‘expect’ method will throw an exception when you tend to do that on*
>   *methods that are final. This might give you an IllegalStateException*
>   *with the message : “no last call on a mock available”. This basically*
>   *means “Help I could not mock this call, and now you want me to mock it*
>   *anyway!”. Step back a bit and think how this EasyMock Class Extension*
>   *would work in order to Mock existing classes? What would you do? Yes,*
>   *you would extend this class, and override the methods! That is what*
>   *the EasyMock Class Extension does. So what happens when you make a*
>   *method final? You cannot override it! If you have any*
>   *IllegalStateException from the EasyMock Class Extension, check your*
>   *methods you tend to ‘expect’ (override) if they are marked “final”.*
>   *Remove the “final” keyword and you will be able to continue your work.*
>   -***Stefan Hendriks***

i dont have any final class, and im using listed jar files:

easymock-2.3.jar

unitils-easymock-3.3.jar

easymockclassextension-2.3.jar

do in need to update my jar files ?

Comment: Look how configurate EasyMock http://easymock.org/user-guide.html and similar with your exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494969/easymock-3-0-mocking-class-throws-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-last-call

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, btw im using unitils because it is required by my mentor to me. i found this is exception weird i already configure to unitils-enable, and i always got the exception i mention above, cant figure it out how to fix it.

Comment: btw here is my ref. 

For Spring - http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-spring.html#
For EasyMock - http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-easymock.html
For Injecting MockObject - http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-inject.html